# How to remove un-wanted multiple sign (e.g. &, %, @) sign from database records

Tags: mysql, sign

I have trouble to remove multiple unwanted sign in MySql database as too huge.
Is there any availabe script to remove that sign?

sample Record With multiple sign :-

```
[]No. 11, Persiaran Bukit [] Satu&[]Taman @Sri %Nibong
```

Answer (score 1):

use `REPLACE` function.

```
UPDATE tablename
SET ColName = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Colname, '&', ''), '@', ''), '%', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest here is prepare a table that contains all the possible unwanted characters and then process them in one select query using replace function.